# Alert Box with specific functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am getting a JS Alert-box When I am leaving my tabs 1st time.
But would like to get it as windows alert - any idea on basis of my code.
Also that should have a OK and Cancel Button - Ok > Next Tab
                                               Cancel> Same tab

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    B.initB();
var 3firstTimeMsg = true;
var 4FirstTimeMsg = true;
$(".3a-tab").click(function(){
    if(3firstTimeMsg == true)
        {
            alert("If you leave this page, any information you've entered will be lost.");
            3firstTimeMsg = false;
        }   
    });
    $(".3b-tab").click(function(){
    if(4FirstTimeMsg == true)
    {
        alert("If you leave this page, any information you've entered will be lost.");
        4FirstTimeMsg = false;
    }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That would probably be a confirm box:

```
if(3firstTimeMsg == true) {
    3firstTimeMsg = confirm("If you leave this page, any information you've entered will be lost.");
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/EUyPe/1/)